# Google Ads in Flutter not showing ads every time on Android?

Tags: flutter, google-ad-manager, google-mobile-ads

I'm using this package -> [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) for Google Ads in Flutter. With iOS everything works perfectly fine but on android sometimes I have this error

**I/flutter (28818): AdManagerBannerAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Internal error., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: COv_-LbOr4IDFUPydwodUiUGNA, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [AdapterResponseInfo(adapterClassName: com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter, latencyMillis: 60001, description: {

I/flutter (28818):   "Adapter": "com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter",

I/flutter (28818):   "Latency": 60001,

I/flutter (28818):   "Ad Source Name": "",

I/flutter (28818):   "Ad Source ID": "",

I/flutter (28818):   "Ad Source Instance Name": "",

I/flutter (28818):   "Ad Source Instance ID": "",

I/flutter (28818):   "Credentials": {},

I/flutter (28818):   "Ad Error": {

I/flutter (28818):     "Code": 0,

I/flutter (28818):     "Message": "Internal error.",

I/flutter (28818):     "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",

I/flutter (28818):     "Cause": "null"

I/flutter (28818):   }

I/flutter (28818): }, adUnitMapping: {}, adError: AdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Internal error.), adSourceName: , adSourceId: , adSourceInstanceName: , adSourceInstanceId: )], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {}) (Instance of 'AdManagerBannerAd')**

Do you have idea why I got this error and ad is not showing, so sometimes it works perfectly fine but sometimes I got this error. Is this related on my side or google side, is this just a broken response?